# Convergence value of the unique positive real root of ${^{m + 1}x} = {^{m}x} + 1$ as $m$ approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, exponentiation, constants, tetration

As $m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ gets bigger and bigger, the unique positive real root of the equation ${^{m + 1}x} = {^{m}x} + 1$, where ${^{m}x} := x^{x^{x^{\dots}}} \}m\text{-many} \; x\text{'s}$, gets progressively smaller.
Now, since $x > 1$ trivially holds for any $m$ (i.e., $1^{1^{\dots}}=1$ so that $1 \neq 1+1$), it would be interesting to find the convergence value of the serie $x : {^{2}x} = {^{1}x} + 1, x : {^{3}x} = {^{2}x} + 1, x : {^{4}x} = {^{3}x} + 1, \dots, x : {^{m + 1}x} = {^{m}x} + 1$ as $m$ approaches infinity.

In details, we have that
if $m = 1$, then  $1.7767750 < x(m) < 1.7767751$;
if $m = 2$, then  $1.6712921 < x(m) < 1.6712922$;
$\dots$ 
if $m = 11$, then  $1.4837622 < x(m) < 1.4837623$;
and so forth.

Moreover, since it has been proved that $x : {^{2}x} = {^{1}x} + 1$ is transcendental (see Gelfond-Schneider Theorem), can we say the same thing for any $x(m : m \geq 2)$?

Comment: I am starting to be persuaded that the convergence value of x(m) could be e^(1/e), since this is the biggest value of x^x^x^... which does not diverge. How could we prove this (if my conjecture is true)?

Comment: Your statement about $e^{1/e}$ is true. But I don't see how it's connected with transcendentality of the $x(m)$ values.

Comment: Thank you, dear openspace. The last statement about transcendentality is a different topic and we can easily ignore it.
About my guess on the convergence value given by $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$, I think that I can be wrong, since we should have a unique asymptotic value of $x(m)$ such that x^^(m+1)=x^^(m)+$k$, for a given $k$... and this cannot hold for, let's say, $k=1$ and $k=2$ at the same time. Thus, I am starting to expect some convergence value which is just above $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$. Really interested in knowing your point about this issue.

Comment: About convergence rate. $x^{{\ldots}^x}$ will converge iff iterated logarithm ($\log^*_b a = \log_b^* \log_b a + 1$) will exist. So we need $\log_b a \le a $ for all values of $a$ (otherwise this process never stops). This is equivalent to $b \ge a^{1/a}$ (which has the greatest value equals to $e^{1/e}$).

Comment: Your statement about $e^{1/e}$ is certainly true. By computational observations one can find that $1.4447181<x(401)<1.4447182$ where $^{402}x(401)=$$^{401}x(401)+1$. But I'm pretty sure that if we consider the equation $^{m+1}x=$$^{m}x+k$ where $k\in\mathbf{N}$, then the limit of the sequence of the unique positive real root of these equations is again $e^{1/e}$, for all values of $k$. For example, if $k=10^{10}$ and $m=401$, then we have that: $1.4447189058231 < x_k (m) < 1.4447189058232$.

Comment: Using Mathematica (just for fun) I have approximated the value of x(10^6), which is: $x(10^6)\approx 1.44466786102025664$, very closed to $e^{1/e}$.

Comment: @LucaOnnis that's true, since it doesn't matter which constant you're adding. The same argument with iterated logarithm works.